# Change NavigationView header Image using glide.with

Tags: java, android, header, navigationview

I'm having a problem with the following code which I am using to try to change the `header` in the `NavigationView` which I have in my `MainActivity`, but it isn't working. I used the exact same code in my `EditProfile.java` and it changes my profile picture exactly like it is supposed to, but it doesn't seem to be working for the `header` in the `NavigationView`. Anyone can tell me why? Should work the same for both in theory.

Below you have my `MainActivity.java` which contains the `NavigationView` with the `header.xml` and `activity_main.xml` file. I also added my `EditProfile.java` file which I created to change the profile picture and other aspects of the User Profile.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom" />

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
                app:itemIconTint="@color/selector"
                app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_bar" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:itemTextColor="#00ffff"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.e.events;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.e.events.Fragment.HomeFragment;
import com.e.events.Fragment.NotificationsFragment;
import com.e.events.Fragment.ProfileFragment;
import com.e.events.Fragment.SaveFragment;
import com.e.events.Fragment.SearchFragment;
import com.e.events.Model.User;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DrawerLocker, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    ImageView image_profile;

    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

    private Uri mImageUri;
    private StorageTask uploadTask;
    StorageReference storageReference;

    String profileid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //Dealing with the header
        View headerLayout = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        ImageView image_profile = headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);

        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        profileid = prefs.getString("profileid", "none");

        image_profile = findViewById(R.id.image_profile);


    private void userInfo() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(profileid);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (getApplicationContext() == null) {
                    return;
                }

                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(user.getImageurl()).into(image_profile);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EditProfile.java**

```
package com.e.events;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.e.events.Model.User;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask;
import com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;

import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.xml.transform.Result;

public class EditProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView close, checkmark_edit_profile, image_profile;
    TextView change_photo;
    MaterialEditText fullname, username, bio;

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

    private Uri mImageUri;
    private StorageTask uploadTask;
    StorageReference storageReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);

        close = findViewById(R.id.close);
        checkmark_edit_profile = findViewById(R.id.checkmark_edit_profile);
        image_profile = findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
        change_photo = findViewById(R.id.text_view_change_profile_picture);
        fullname = findViewById(R.id.fullname);
        username = findViewById(R.id.username);
        bio = findViewById(R.id.bio);

        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                fullname.setText(user.getFullname());
                username.setText(user.getUsername());
                bio.setText(user.getBio());
                Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(user.getImageurl()).into(image_profile);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        change_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CropImage.activity()
                        .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                        .setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.OVAL)
                        .start(EditProfileActivity.this);
            }
        });

        image_profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CropImage.activity()
                        .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                        .setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.OVAL)
                        .start(EditProfileActivity.this);
            }
        });

        checkmark_edit_profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateProfile(fullname.getText().toString(),
                        username.getText().toString(),
                        bio.getText().toString());

            }
        });
    }

    private void updateProfile(String fullname, String username, String bio) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("fullname", fullname);
        hashMap.put("username", username);
        hashMap.put("bio", bio);

        reference.updateChildren(hashMap);
    }

    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));
    }

    private void uploadImage() {
        final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setMessage("Uploading");
        pd.show();

        if (mImageUri != null) {
            final StorageReference filereference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
            +"."+ getFileExtension(mImageUri));

            uploadTask = filereference.putFile(mImageUri);
            uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation() {
                @Override
                public Object then(@NonNull Task task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }

                    return filereference.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                        String myUrl = downloadUri.toString();

                        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());

                        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                        hashMap.put("imageurl", ""+myUrl);

                        reference.updateChildren(hashMap);
                        pd.dismiss();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, "Upload Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Image Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    //Ctrl + O

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            mImageUri = result.getUri();

            uploadImage();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something has gone wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="176dp"
    android:background="#e6e6e6"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_profile"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fullname_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image_profile"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:text="John Bilich"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please add more details like if you get exception or what you want to achieve

Comment: Where is the Glide call? I don't see one anywhere in the given code. Please also look into how to put together a [mcve]. A lot of the stuff you've posted is unnecessary, and just makes it harder to track down the issue.

Comment: @MikeM. okay so I changed the code in the MainActivity to include only the necessary components. Hope that's more clear and the Glide call you can see there. Any idea why the profile picture isn't being updated to the one that I choose in my EditProfileActivity?

Comment: @MohammedAlaa I want to be able to change my Profile Picture in my ***fragment_profile.xml*** and ***header*** in the ***NavView*** which I created in my ***MainActivity***, but it uploads / changes the profile picture in the ***ProfileFragment*** just fine, but NOT in the ***header*** and I don't know why... Is something missing in the code?

Comment: Are you certain that `onDataChange()` is running? Are you calling `userInfo()` anywhere? I don't see it in the current code, nor was that method in the original. Also, you've declared `image_profile` twice, and the field is not being assigned. That is, you've declared a local one in the `ImageView image_profile = headerLayout...` line, then reassigned it a few lines down in the `image_profile = findViewById...`. Neither of those is assigning the `image_profile` declared at the top of the class, which is the one used in `onDataChange()`. That should be throwing an Exception, if it were to run.

Comment: @MikeM. it's running because I called ```userInfo()``` in my ```ProfileFragment```. Do I also have to call ```userInfo()``` in my ```MainActivity```? And yeah you're right it's throwing an exception... So I have to assign it to the ```image_profile``` I have in my ```header```?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "called `userInfo()` in my `ProfileFragment`", but to get the `image_profile` field in `MainActivity` assigned correctly, remove `ImageView` from the beginning of the `ImageView image_profile = headerLayout...` line, and delete the `image_profile = findViewById(R.id.image_profile);` line.

Comment: @MikeM. you are the man!!!!!!!!! Did that and called ```userInfo()``` in the MainActivity.java and the header profile picture is changed just like in the profile fragment. ThankYouuuuuuuuuuuuu